# Asp.net dropdown list default value not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list that I bind this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Can't write !Page.IsPostBack because this is a User control which doesn't  
    //exist at page load
    if (ddlConditionType.Items.Count == 0)  
        PopulateDDL();
}
private void PopulateDDL()
{
    MyDdl.DataSource = MyObjectList; //Containing A, B, C
    MyDdl.DataBind();
    MyDdl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
}
```

The result expected is to have a dropdown with those items:

- String.Empty
- A
- B
- C

Or the actual result is

- A
- B
- C

I've set `AppendDataBoundItems = true` and this is the results:

- String.Empty
- A
- B
- C
- A
- B
- C

Looks like it bind the ddl a first time, add the item, and rebind it again. Of course, there is no other place in my project were I bind the ddl a second time.

For now I've found a workaround which is the following:

```
MyObjectList.Insert(0,new MyObject()); //Which will result in a empty ddl item 
MyDdl.DataSource = MyObjectList;
MyDdl.DataBind();
```

I'd like to understand what is going on there.

Comment: In which event do you execute that code? Could you show the whole event code?

Comment: The ddl is in a user control and I load it in the Page_Load event. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use Clear Method Befor DataBind,

```
MyDdl.Items.Clear();
```

Where do you bind the dropdown? on the page_load?
if you want to bind your dropdown at Page_Load, you have check the postback status:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    MyDdl.DataSource = MyObjectList; //Containing A, B, C
    MyDdl.DataBind();
    MyDdl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
}
```

Comment: I've tried with `MyDdl.Items.Clear();` and it didn't worked. And the ddl is in a user control so I can't check with `Page.IsPostBack` because the ddl doesn't exist the first time the page is loaded, so I have `if (ddlConditionType.Items.Count == 0)PopulateDDL()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi that happen because you don't put your method inside postback like this

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

      PopulateDDL();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

at your page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
            MyUserControl.PopulateDDL();
    }
}
```

at your user control

```
public void PopulateDDL()
{
    MyDdl.DataSource = MyObjectList; //Containing A, B, C
    MyDdl.DataBind();
    MyDdl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
}
```